# Is it possible to use Grover's Search Algorithm on an Array in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, quantum-computing

I have an array, and am wondering if using Grover's search algorithm would work on it. Is this possible to do in Node.js? Would I use something like `quantum-circuit` to achieve this goal?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi.  This is a good read in regards to Grover's search:
https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~imarkov/pubs/jour/cise05-grov.pdf

Comment: @ThomasBitonti thanks for that amazing resource! I'll make sure to check it out. :)